# Are there any repositories for Fedora 3?

Tags: fedora, yum

Is there any alive repository for my Fedora Core 3 Linux?

(I want to use the `yum` command but one error comes and tells that `base url is not valid`)

Any help to find any alive repository is very much appreciated :)

Comment: Fedora 3 is _long_ gone, this is just of historic interest. There might be working repositories at the places @YaseiNoUmi cites, but when I groped around there looking for an old Red Hat, what I found had pieces missing.

Comment: Be aware that Fedora Core 3 has known serious security flaws even with all updates applied. Any local user will be able to get root access easily. Make sure your system is well isolated. When you get a hands, I suggest migrating to CentOS or RHEL, which _does_ offer this kind of decade-long security update lifetime.

Comment: https://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it moved to a new location:

- http://archive.kernel.org/fedora-archive/core/3/i386/os/
- http://archive.kernel.org/fedora-archive/extras/3/i386/

Comment: Thanks for the link Yasei... I'm still using fedora 3. I know it's very old but a system that i'm working on right now is currently installed in fedora 3. This link help me installing packages... Keep it up...